# Как сделать кнопки одного размера в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Есть две кнопки

```
Button button1 = new Button("button");
Button button2 = new Button("button_button");
```

которые я располагаю в

```
VBox vBox = new VBox(5.0);
vBox .getChildren().add(button1);
vBox .getChildren().add(button1);
```

Размер кнопок определяется размером текста внутри кнопки, как сделать, чтобы они все были одного размера
Пробовал менять свойства, типа

```
button1.setMaxWidth(200.0);
```

или

```
button1.setMinWidth(200.0);
```

размер кнопки при этом не меняется

Comment: Просто `button1.setMinWidth(200.0);` пробовали?

Comment: извиняюсь, ошибка по тексту была. 
Да, пробовал, кнопка ни как не реагирует. Я не пойму почему. Я так пониаю, что где-то включено свойство задания авторазмера кнопок, но как его отключить?

Comment: Попробуйте задавать сразу все три: setMinWidth, setPrefWidth, setMaxWidth

Comment: Вот прямо из кода:
 buttonFilter.setMinWidth(150.0);
 buttonFilter.setMaxWidth(150.0);
 buttonFilter.setPrefWidth(150.0);
кнопка осталась без изименений

Comment: Я так понимаю, что эта штука должна работать? Значит у меня в коде что-то не так. Щас попробую переделать все Vbox и HBox. Может я ваще зря связался с этими Box-ми? Мне поначалу показалось, что с ними удобнее. А теперь их целая куча на форме

Comment: Какая штука? Все должно работать, у меня нет никаких проблем с VBox.

Comment: Все работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8SBR.png Добавьте полный код инициализации окна в вопрос.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, заново сформировал все VBox и HBox, теперь кнопки меняют размер в соответствии с setMinWidth. Где-то была ошибка в коде. Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 0):

Размер задается setMinWidth, все работает, где-то была проблема в моем коде